# Replace issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My string is Following:

```
string mystring ="Test1234\r\ntest1234\r\ntest1234\r\ntest dhjfadhdfsfdsjfdf";
```

It comes from a database and I want to display it in a label as usual format. So, I want to replace `\r\n` to `<br>`.

I tried using `NewString= mystring .Replace('\r\n','<br>');`, but it didn't work.

I got the following error

> To many characters in character literal`.If this is not a correct way to do suggest.Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean it is not work?where are u getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, replacing the single quotes with double quotes:

```
var NewString= mystring.Replace("\r\n","<br>");
```

Using single quotes indicates that you are going to specify a char instead of a string. You then passed in a string literal consisting of two characters ( the \r and the \n) rather than a single character, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you're using `'`. you need to use `"`.

Anyhow, `Label` *does not* format HTML tags, which means, `<br />` will look like `<br />` and not like a new line.

for that, you need to use either a `span` or a `div` or anything similar.

You can replace your `Label` with a `span`:

```
<span id="span1" runat="server" />
```

and then use

```
span1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("your string here with html tags"));
```

Comment: You don't need to replace the asp:Label with a span to do that! However, if you do use a span, you can use `span1.InnerHtml = "your string with html";` which I find easier on the eyes.